# Powershell: Diplay JSON object properties in same order defined in JSON input

Tags: json, powershell

I have the below code where I am looking to display the output of the JSON input properties in the same order using powershell. But looks like the `Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty`(It is mandatory that I need to filter `NoteProperty` here) is sorting the properties and not able to get the desired output.

```
$JsonConfig = @"
    {
        "PostStep": {
            "AppExists": {
                "AppName": "Agent"
            },
            "Version": {
                "Number": "2.3"
            },
            "Execution": {
                "Argument": "/uninstall",
                "Installer": "C:\\WFBS\\Tool.exe"
            }
        }
    }
"@

$OrderedObject =   $JsonConfig | ConvertFrom-Json
$StepObject = $OrderedObject.PostStep

Foreach ($Property in $StepObject | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty) {
    Write-Host $($Property.Name)
}
```

**Output:**

```
AppExists
Execution
Version
```

**Desired Output:**

```
AppExists
Version
Execution
```

Any suggestions would be really helpful on how I can fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`psobject` hidden memberset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_intrinsic_members?view=powershell-7.3#object-views) to access the properties in order:

```
foreach ($Property in $StepObject.psobject.Properties) {
    Write-Host $($Property.Name)
}
```